# Callback function after the jquery .stop() method

Tags: jquery

Hello I want to use the stop() function in jquery on an animation and fire a callback function after the animation stops. After using .finish() the  "done" callback does fire but it doesnt let me reset the position. Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/enx5we0g/6/

```
("#wrapper1").animate(
{
    left : 0 + windowWidth
}, {
  step: function( now, tween ) {

 if(now >100){

  $(this).stop();

 }


},

easing: "linear",
always: function(){
$("#wrapper1").css({'left':'0px'})

}


});
```

I want the position of the object to go to the left after the animation stops. How can I do this?

Comment: your fiddle is not doing anything

Comment: sorry! It works now